# No Such Module in Vendored frameworks but only in Release configuration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcframework

I have created custom library using [react-native-builder-bob](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob) contains my third party .xcframework that I put it in podspec vendored framework

Everything is fine, build success and runtime is runnable in Debug configuration

But when I switch to and build in Release configuration, it says "No Such Module 'FrameworkName'"

I've checked on build settings that I have similar configuration between Debug and Release